# Cannot find gpg.conf and gpg-agent.conf using gpg 2.2.12 on Raspbian Buster

Tags: raspberry-pi, gnupg, raspbian, gpg-agent, msmtp

I am using gpg to encrypt my email password that I pass on to msmtp in order to send email.

I initially ran `gpg --full-gen-key` to generate a pair of keys. During the process, it asked me for a passphrase. The process has completed successfully.

Secondly, I encrypted my email password by running `gpg --encrypt --output ~/.msmtp/msmtp-myaccount-pass.gpg --recipient my@gpg-email -`

I configured msmtp to use `passwordeval` and tried a to send a test email. While sending, gpg asked me to enter the passphrase. This was done and the email was sent successfully.

Now, I would like to send system reports email to myself from this headless raspberry pi server and in order to do that I am building a script which will be run by `cron`. Given that the server will be unattended, the passphrase needs to be cached and I understood that the safest way to do that is by using `gpg-agent`.

In order to use `gpg-agent`, I need to edit `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` and add `use-agent`. I also need to edit `gpg-agent.conf` to customise the caching period. This is where I have reached a dead-end.

I cannot find the file `gpg-conf` nor the file `gpg-agent.conf`.

When I list the `.gnupg` directory, I get:

```
drwx------ 2 pi pi 4096 Apr  5 22:11 crls.d
drwx------ 2 pi pi 4096 Apr  5 22:15 openpgp-revocs.d
drwx------ 2 pi pi 4096 Apr  5 22:15 private-keys-v1.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 2475 Apr  5 22:15 pubring.kbx
-rw------- 1 pi pi   32 Apr  5 22:11 pubring.kbx~
-rw------- 1 pi pi  600 Apr  5 22:43 random_seed
-rw------- 1 pi pi 1280 Apr  5 22:18 trustdb.gpg
```

I confirm that `gpg-agent` is running as a process.

I looked for a solution online and some suggest to copy skeleton files from `/usr/share/gnupg` but no skeleton files available as per below:

```
distsigkey.gpg  help.de.txt  help.fi.txt  help.it.txt  help.pt_BR.txt  help.tr.txt
help.be.txt     help.el.txt  help.fr.txt  help.ja.txt  help.ro.txt     help.zh_CN.txt
help.ca.txt     help.eo.txt  help.gl.txt  help.nb.txt  help.ru.txt     help.zh_TW.txt
help.cs.txt     help.es.txt  help.hu.txt  help.pl.txt  help.sk.txt     sks-keyservers.netCA.pem
help.da.txt     help.et.txt  help.id.txt  help.pt.txt  help.sv.txt
```

I would be grateful if you could assist me in configuring `gpg-agent` regarding the cache time for the passphrase.

For reference, I am using Raspbian Buster on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

> I cannot find the file gpg-conf nor the file gpg-agent.conf

It's no big deal, just create it. Without it Gnupg is running with default options.

If you want to manually enter the passphrase on startup, then memorize it for a certain amount of time the option you are interested in is `default-cache-ttl` but it's not the only one:

> gpg-agent can be configured via ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf file. The
>   configuration options are listed in gpg-agent(1). For example you can
>   change cache ttl for unused keys:
>
> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
>
> default-cache-ttl 3600
>
> Tip: To cache your passphrase for the whole session, please run the
>   following command:
>
> $ /usr/lib/gnupg/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset XXXXX
>
> where XXXXX is the keygrip. You can get its value when running gpg
>   --with-keygrip -K. The passphrase will be stored until gpg-agent is restarted. If you set up default-cache-ttl value, it will take
>   precedence.

Source: [GnuPG](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#gpg-agent)

Comment: I tried gpg-preset-passphrase but I am getting: gpg-preset-passphrase: cachingbpassphrase failed: Not supported.

Comment: "This program works with GnuPG 2 and later. GnuPG 1.x is not supported." - Source: [gnupg.org documentation: gpg-preset-passphrase](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpg_002dpreset_002dpassphrase.html). Can you confirm your version by running `gpg --version` ? You might have both V1 and V2 available on your system, then you can replace `gpg` with `gpg2` in your command line.